# Directory API: error updating user primaryEmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I'm trying to use the Directory API to change a G Suite user's account name / primary email.

Currently the user has primary email `user@olddomain.com` and an alias `user@newdomain.com`. According to [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) and the [Apps Script docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) I should be able to change the property `primaryEmail` using Google Apps Script.

```
function minimalRepro() {
  var result = AdminDirectory.Users.patch({ primaryEmail: "user@newdomain.com" }, "user@olddomain.com");
  Logger.log(result.primaryEmail);
}
```

**Produces `error: Invalid Input: primary_user_email (line 2, file "MinimalRepro")`.**

I've tried a number of alternatives (`.update` instead of `.patch`, using a `userId` instead of `user@olddomain.com`) and the error is the same.

If I use `{ primary_user_email: XXX }` for the patch object instead, the code runs without error but does not update the user; `result.primaryEmail` contains the old email, and the changes never appear in the user's G Suite Profile.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the "alias" part was the problem. I removed the domain from G Suite as a "domain alias" and added it as "another domain" instead. After making this change, the patch call succeeded and the change was immediately visible in the Admin Console.